# iOS - Broadcast Upload Extension - UserDidFinishSetup - pass parameters from Container app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I am developing an app using **Broadcast Upload Extension** - I would like to know how to pass parameters into the BroadcastViewController so I can them pass them onto the **CompleteRequest** method (**userSetup** parameter). Or am I suppose to reference the Container app somehow and get the parameters from there?

code from **BroadcastViewController**:

```
  public partial class BroadcastViewController : UIViewController
        {
            protected BroadcastViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
            {
                // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
            }

            public void UserDidFinishSetup()
            {
// NEED TO OBTAIN HERE PARAMETERS
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ScreenShareExtensionUI: UserDidFinishSetup");
                // Broadcast url that will be returned to the application
                var broadcastURL = NSUrl.FromString("http://broadcastURL_example/stream1");

                // Service specific broadcast data example which will be supplied to the process extension during broadcast
                var keys = new[] { "channelName", "token", "appId" };
                var objects = new[] { "channelName", "token", "appId" };
                var setupInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using App Groups capability. This allows me to fill in the parameters in the container app and then retrieve them in the extension like this:

```
var plist = new NSUserDefaults("group.com.foo.ss", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
            var agoraApi = plist.StringForKey("agoraApi");
            var agoraRoomId = plist.DoubleForKey("agoraRoomId");
            var agoraToken = plist.StringForKey("agoraToken");
            var agoraUserId = plist.DoubleForKey("agoraUserId");
```